# Express + Jade giving me syntax errors

Tags: express, pug

I'm using Jade + Express for the first time and just playing around with it to see what can be done.

I'm using Brian Fords [seed app](http://briantford.com/blog/angular-express.html) as a base for my learning as well as using Jade (the templating engine) for the first time.

However, when I try to write out a fresh `index.jade` file, Express keeps giving me either syntax errors or indent token errors.

Here;s the code im trying to use.

```
doctype 5
   html(lang="en" ng-app="myApp")
   head
     meta(charset='utf8')
     base(href='/')
     link(rel='stylesheet' href='/css/app.css')
     title= pageTitle
   body
     block body
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

*edit*

The errors given are:

```
500 Error: /Users/Keva161/Documents/Web Dev/Webapps/Node/angular-express-seed/views/layout.jade:2 1| doctype 5 > 2| html(lang="en" ng-app="myApp") 3| head 4| meta(charset='utf8') 5| base(href='/') unexpected token "indent"
1| doctype 5
> 2| html(lang="en" ng-app="myApp")
3| head
4| meta(charset='utf8')
5| base(href='/')
unexpected token "indent"
at Object.Parser.parseExpr (/Users/Keva161/Documents/Web Dev/Webapps/Node/angular-express-seed/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:241:15)
at Object.Parser.parse (/Users/Keva161/Documents/Web Dev/Webapps/Node/angular-express-seed/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:134:25)
at Object.Parser.parse (/Users/Keva161/Documents/Web Dev/Webapps/Node/angular-express-seed/node_modules/jade/lib/parser.js:140:24)
at parse (/Users/Keva161/Documents/Web Dev/Webapps/Node/angular-express-seed/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:100:62)
at Object.exports.compile (/Users/Keva161/Documents/Web Dev/Webapps/Node/angular-express-seed/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:163:9)
at Object.exports.render (/Users/Keva161/Documents/Web Dev/Webapps/Node/angular-express-seed/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:215:17)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/Keva161/Documents/Web Dev/Webapps/Node/angular-express-seed/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:243:13)
at View.render (/Users/Keva161/Documents/Web Dev/Webapps/Node/angular-express-seed/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:75:8)
at Function.app.render (/Users/Keva161/Documents/Web Dev/Webapps/Node/angular-express-seed/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:505:10)
at ServerResponse.res.render (/Users/Keva161/Documents/Web Dev/Webapps/Node/angular-express-seed/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:717:7)
```

Comment: Could you post alongside the errors which are thrown?

Comment: have edited the first post with the exact errors given.. sorry about that!

Comment: Perfect!.. Jade does say you that it wasn't expecting the indentation.. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think jade was interpreting your html to be inside the doctype. Whereas its not!

```
doctype 5
html(lang="en" ng-app="myApp")
 head
   base(href='website.domain/url')
   link(rel='stylesheet', href='css/app.css', type='text/css')
   title pageTitle
 meta(http-equiv="content-type", content="#{contentType}; charset=UTF-8")
 body
```

Also am not sure what `block body` was intended for?!
AFAIK, `block body` will be used when you are using another view file and appending text to your layout file.

Answer (score 1):

> html(lang="en" ng-app="myApp")

You may need to add a comma, like so

html(lang="en", ng-app="myApp")